# expected unqualified-id before '{' token and expected initializer before "main"

Tags: c

hi im a beginner in c and now i have two problem with my programm thank you for helping me

```
#include<stdio.h>
int reverse (int x)

main()
{
    int x;
    int v,z,t,a,i=1;
    printf("enter your number:\n");
    scanf("%u",&x);
    t=x;
    while(t>0)
    {
        t=t/10;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",i-1);
    a=(i-1)%2;
    if(a=1)
    {
        x=x/10;
        z=x%10;
        v=10*(int reverse (int x))+z
        printf("%d",v);
        printf("%d",x);
    }
    else
        printf("%d",int reverse (int x));
}

int reverse(int x);
{
    if(x>=10)
        reverse(n/10);
    printf("%d",n%10);
    return;
}


         here are my errors:
```

[Error] C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled5.cpp:3: error: expected initializer before "main"
[Error] C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled5.cpp:26: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token

```
  my compiler is c free 5.0
```

thanks

Comment: Your first problem is by not formatting the code.

Comment: C-Free is not a compiler, it's an IDE.

Comment: what do you want your program to do??

Answer (score 0):

Missing a semicolon in function prototype definition

```
int reverse (int x);
                   ^
```

---

```
v=10*(int reverse (int x))+z
```

Thats not how a function is called, you have call like this

```
v=10*(reverse(x))+z; //a missing semicolon here too
```

---

Your function`reverse()` is not returning anything.

```
int reverse(int x);
{
    if(x>=10)
        reverse(n/10);
    printf("%d",n%10);
    return;            //Return whatever int you want to here
}
```

---

*Please go through some good Basic C programming book.*